# Python: App can't find a module, regardless of environment

Tags: python, python-2.7

An application can't import the "urllib" module from the package "six". But I can import it from a test script in the same environment.  Can't figure out why.

```
❯ nova
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/nova", line 6, in <module>
    from novaclient.shell import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/shell.py", line 45, in <module>
    from novaclient import client
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/novaclient/client.py", line 34, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib import parse
ImportError: No module named urllib
```

But if I run a simple test script, it's just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from six.moves.urllib import parse
foo = parse.urlsplit("http://foo.net/florp/blorp?blap=blork")
print foo
```

Here's the output:

```
❯ ./test.py 
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='foo.net', path='/florp/blorp', query='blap=blork', fragment='')
```

Tried setting my PYTHONPATH explicitly, tried it under virtualenv... nothing..

Any ideas?  (Sorry I'm not a Python programmer, so it may be something obvious).

Comment: Where is `six` installed? (If you don't know how to see that, have your simple test script `print(six.__file__)`. What did you try explicitly setting your `PYTHONPATH` to?

Comment: what does `which -a python` output from bash?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Why are you expecting that to matter? He's running `./test.py`, which has an explicit `#!/usr/bin/python2`, and `/usr/bin/nova`, which is clearly looking in `/usr` rather than somewhere else.

Comment: @abarnert, so you cannot have two python installs in `/usr`?

Comment: @thermans If you are running the test script having shebang - it will ignore your current virtualenv. You shall test it by `$ python test.py`, this has a chance to use current Python in your environment.

Comment: @abarnert `six` is in `/usr/lib/python/2.7/site-packages`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `$ which -a python2
/usr/bin/python2
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 9 Jul  1 13:42 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You cannot have two Python 2.7 installs in `/usr`. The second `/usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2.7`, `/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so`, etc. will overwrite the first one. I suppose if you went out of your way to pass `--prefix=/usr` but then override all of the additional configure options so you ended up with `/usr/bin/python2.7-a` and `/usr/bin/python2.7-b` and `/usr/lib/python2.7-a/` and so on, you could make it work, but I can't imagine anyone doing that by accident, or not thinking it worthy of mentioning when they have a path problem…

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of the `nova` program—or, if it's an open source app, just point us to the source? Or, even better, can you temporarily modify it (or, if it's a shell script that runs a Python script, the script that it runs) to add `import sys; print sys.path, sys.version, sys.executable` at the top? It's hard to imagine how it could not have `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and still be able to import its own submodules with the paths you showed, but… better to rule it out for sure.

Comment: @abarnert, you can have two python installs in /usr and /usr/local etc... I asked what the outcome of which -a python was to see exactly what python installations the OP has as if there was only the default /usr/bin/python there should be no issues with  python finding packages, the OP's issues more than likely stem from having   different python installs or the editing the paths manually.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Sure, because `/usr` and `/usr/local` are different prefixes. But you can't (easily) have two copies of the same Python X.Y version in the same prefix. And a shebang for `/usr/bin/python2` and error messages about `/usr/lib/python2.7` are clearly an installation in `/usr`, not `/usr/local`.